# how to create a new column by loop?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have been using a data set on housing for Machine learning. while trying to reduce the dimensions of the dataset i wanted to merge 2 columns namely 'yr_built' and 'yr_renovated' to a new column 'age' ( of the house) .

i am trying to create a new column age from 2 predefined columns ((year_built) and (year_renovated)). the column of year renovated has values like year (eg 1991 if renovated) or 0 if not renovated.

The logic i am trying to use here is that If renovation happened, age of building is current year - year of renovation i.e.

```
[age = 2019 - year_renovated]
```

If no renovation has taken place: age of building is current year - year of construction i.e.

```
[age = 2019 - year_built]
```

the image of the ppnew data is displayed in following picture

I have tried to use a for loop for the same and the code is as follows:

[the dataframe is in this pic attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaYfl.png)

```
for i in pp['age']:
if pp['yr_renovated'] = 0:
    ppnew['age'] = 2019 - pp['yr_built']
else:
   ppnew['age'] = 2019 - pp['yr_renovated']
```

and i also tried to use

```
for i in pp['age']:
if pp['yr_renovated'] == 0: #truth value
    ppnew['age'] = 2019 - pp['yr_built']
else:
   ppnew['age'] = 2019 - pp['yr_renovated']
```

the error says boolean error

plz help with the code.

thank you

Comment: `for row in df.iterrows()`?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: hey @desertnaut i have jus started learning python and machine learning.! and this is related to data preprocessing. hope you now understand why i have included machine learning tag

Comment: I see; for the future, please keep in mind that tags are about the *content* of the question, *not* its context.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['age'] = list(zip(2019 - df['yr_built'], 2019 - df['yr_renovated'], df['yr_renovated'] != 0))
df

Out[1]:

        price   bedrooms    bathrooms   floors  view    grade   yr_built    yr_renovated    zipcode age
0   2219000     3           1.00        1       0       7       1955        0               500178  (64, 2019, False)
1   5380000     3           2.25        2       0       7       1951        1991            500125  (68, 28, True)
2   1800000     2           1.00        1       0       6       1933        0               500028  (86, 2019, False)
3   6040000     4           3.00        1       0       7       1965        0               500136  (54, 2019, False)
4   5100000     3           2.00        1       0       8       1987        0               500074  (32, 2019, False)


df['age'] = [(x[0],x[1])[x[2]] for x in df['age']]

Out[2]:


    price   bedrooms    bathrooms   floors  view    grade   yr_built    yr_renovated    zipcode age
0   2219000     3       1.00        1       0       7       1955        0               500178  64
1   5380000     3       2.25        2       0       7       1951        1991            500125  28
2   1800000     2       1.00        1       0       6       1933        0               500028  86
3   6040000     4       3.00        1       0       7       1965        0               500136  54
4   5100000     3       2.00        1       0       8       1987        0               500074  32
```

Comment: thank you so much.. i am learning to program.. can you explain the above in brief!!

Comment: first step - you prepare tuples for every row, like this (64, 2019, False), (62, 28, True) - is it clear? Second step you do this (x[0], x[1])x[2], so in real data it looks like (64, 2019)[False] or (64, 2019)[0] - you select element with index 0 from tuples - it is 64.  And so on with the next line (62, 28)[True] is (62, 28)[1] - you select element with index 1 - it is 28

Comment: does this solution and explanation help?